# how to join two tables with a where condition and display the records

Tags: php, mysql

So I had a hard time finding a good answer on Stack. I'm looking to run a query that combines the information on two tables together. So far this is what i have got. The actual scenario is as follows:

I will try to explain a bit more from my side to achieve this:

I have two tables  :

```
Comparitive_st_sup
___________________

id  | tender_id | item_name | slno | supplier_name | prod_description
________________________________________________________________________

1       401        Collinear   1      OnlineMetals    Description comes here    
2       401        Filter      2      OnlineMetals    Description comes here
3       401        Antenna     3      OnlineMetals    Description Comes here
4       455        Primer      1      KR Electronics  Description comes here
5       455        Chock       2      KR Electronics  Description comes here


comparitive_st_tech_compliance
_______________________________

id | tender_id | item_name  | slno | supplier_name  | tech_analyst_comment
__________________________________________________________________________

1      401        Collinear    1      OnlineMetals     90%
2      401        Filter       2      OnlineMetals     25%
3      401        Antenna      3      OnlineMetals     87%
4      455        Primer       1      KR Electronics   64%
5      455        Chick        2      KR Electronics   80%

Now i am expecting a result like:

401    Collinear     1    OnlineMetals    Description comes here   90%
401    Filter        2    OnlineMetals    Description comes here   25%
401    Antenna       3    OnlineMetals    Description comes here   87%
```

As per the tender_id selected the value is passing as a querystring and the records has to be displayed accordingly. Help appreciated..

I tried this, but result is not proper:

```
 Select comparitive_st_sup.*,
  comparitive_st_sup.tender_id As tender_id1,
  comparitive_st_sup.supplier_name As supplier_name1,
  comparitive_st_sup.slno As slno1,
  comparitive_st_sup.prod_description As prod_description1,
  comparitive_st_sup.item_name As item_name1,
  comparitive_st_sup.total As total1,
  comparitive_st_tech_compliance.tech_analyst_comment
  From comparitive_st_tech_compliance
  Right Join comparitive_st_sup On comparitive_st_sup.tender_id =
  comparitive_st_tech_compliance.tender_id
  Where comparitive_st_sup.tender_id = 401
```

I need to display all the fields from comparitive_st_sup and only one field (tech_analyst_comment) with a where condition tender_id. Now the records are duplicating. Instead of 3 records to show, it is showing 9 records. Am i making any mistake?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use a `RIGHT JOIN` ?

Comment: [A visual explanation of SQL Joins](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

Comment: Can i achieve with just a inner join?

Comment: No, iam not getting the desired output. Right Join and Inner Join is showing the same output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want or can't `GROUP BY`, you could try a sub-query. You can also `ORDER BY` date/id in the sub-query.

```sql
SELECT
    cs.*,
    cs.tender_id AS tender_id1,
    cs.supplier_name AS supplier_name1,
    cs.slno AS slno1,
    cs.prod_description AS prod_description1,
    cs.item_name AS item_name1,
    cs.total AS total1,
    (
        SELECT
            ct.tech_analyst_comment
        FROM comparitive_st_tech_compliance AS ct
        WHERE ct.tender_id = cs.tender_id
        LIMIT 1
    ) AS tech_analyst_comment
FROM comparitive_st_sup AS cs
WHERE cs.tender_id = 401
```

---

**LE:**
IF and ONLY IF slno is the same identifier in both of your tables ( `comparitive_st_sup.slno = comparitive_st_tech_compliance.slno` ), than you can join them with the extra join argument of `AND comparitive_st_sup.slno = comparitive_st_tech_compliance.slno` so your initial query will look something like this:

```sql
Select comparitive_st_sup.*,
  comparitive_st_sup.tender_id As tender_id1,
  comparitive_st_sup.supplier_name As supplier_name1,
  comparitive_st_sup.slno As slno1,
  comparitive_st_sup.prod_description As prod_description1,
  comparitive_st_sup.item_name As item_name1,
  comparitive_st_sup.total As total1,
  comparitive_st_tech_compliance.tech_analyst_comment
From comparitive_st_tech_compliance
Right Join comparitive_st_sup On
    comparitive_st_sup.tender_id = comparitive_st_tech_compliance.tender_id AND
    comparitive_st_sup.slno = comparitive_st_tech_compliance.slno
Where comparitive_st_sup.tender_id = 401
```

but if slno differs in table *_st_sup and *_tech_compliance than you will need to add a relationship between the products and comments beside the tender_id

```sql
comparitive_st_tech_compliance
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | tender_id | product_id | item_name  | slno | supplier_name  | tech_analyst_comment |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | 401       |     1      | Collinear  |   1  | OnlineMetals   | description          |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

where comparitive_st_tech_compliance.product_id is Comparitive_st_sup.id, which also brings me to the point where I would suggest you to change your database schema ( structure )

**Side note:** So from your database structure, one thing to point out is that it's poorly designed. You have duplicate fields in both tabels, so if you need to update for ex. supplier_name you will need to update all of your tables. Now assuming you are willing to make the changes, I would suggest to split up your data into 3 tables, not taking into account that slno may be an identifier between the 2 tables.

```sql
comparative_supplier
+---------------------+
| id | supplier_name  |
+---------------------+
| 1  | OnlineMetals   |
| 2  | KR Electronics |
+---------------------+

comparitive_st_sup
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | tender_id | supplier_id | slno | item_name | prod_description |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1  | 401       |      1      |   1  | Collinear | description      |
| 2  | 401       |      1      |   2  | Filter    | description      |
| 3  | 401       |      1      |   3  | Antenna   | description      |
| 4  | 455       |      2      |   1  | Primer    | description      |
| 5  | 455       |      2      |   2  | Chock     | description      |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+

comparitive_st_tech_compliance
+-----------------------------------------+
| id   | id_supply | tech_analyst_comment |
+-----------------------------------------+
| 15   |     1     |         90%          |
| 56   |     2     |         25%          |
| 123  |     3     |         87%          |
| 412  |     4     |         64%          |
| 684  |     5     |         80%          |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

with this table structure you can easily join your tables without duplicate entries and change fields without the need to update all your tables.

```sql
SELECT
    cs.tender_id, sn.supplier_name, cs.slno, cs.item_name,
    cs.prod_description, ct.tech_analyst_comment
FROM comparitive_st_sup AS cs
LEFT JOIN comparative_supplier AS sn ON sn.id = cs.supplier_id
LEFT JOIN comparitive_st_tech_compliance AS ct ON ct.id_supply = cs.id
WHERE cs.tender_id = 401
```

or just change your st_sup table and include the the tech comment, because the 2 tables only differ by the tech comment and  product description

Comment: This is working fine except that i think there is a problem with this subquery "SELECT ct.tech_analyst_comment FROM comparitive_st_tech_compliance AS ct WHERE ct.tender_id = cs.tender_id LIMIT 1"... Because tech_analyst_comment is different for each tender_id, as of now tech_analyst_comment all showing same numbers since its just taking the first record..

Comment: if you could edit your question to include some table structure and some data with it, you could get a better result. as for the guessing goes, are you trying to list the tech comments and also fetching the data assosiated with it? lets say: st_sup -> id, tender_id, product_name; st_tech -> id, tender_id, comment; there isn't a relation between st_sup and st_tech for a specific product,just tender_id, which is the relation between the the current user I'm guessing. so you should build a relationship between product and comment, than your initial query may work. st_sup-> pd_id; st_tech->pd_id

Comment: i have updated my answer with a possible query which may work, also a suggestion for your current database schema

Comment: Awesome bro..its working fine now. I created a new field calld item_id and made a relationship between both the tables. Its working fine..Really so great of you. Really thank you for your time for this novice. God bless you. Thank you once more....

Comment: Your welcome. Also I highly recommand the 3 table split up. Its more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

from your comment, I believe comparitive_st_tech_compliance has more then one row against a row in comparitive_st_sup table for a single tender_id.
if it is so then it will return multiple row doesn't matter which Join you use.

Comment: Both comparitive_st_sup and comparitive_st_tech_compliance has 3 records for a single tender_id..

Comment: so that's why instead of 3 records, it is giving an output of 9 records?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to do so here:

```
Select comparitive_st_sup.*,
  comparitive_st_sup.tender_id As tender_id1,
  comparitive_st_sup.supplier_name As supplier_name1,
  comparitive_st_sup.slno As slno1,
  comparitive_st_sup.prod_description As prod_description1,
  comparitive_st_sup.item_name As item_name1,
  comparitive_st_sup.total As total1,
  comparitive_st_tech_compliance.tech_analyst_comment
  From comparitive_st_tech_compliance
  Where comparitive_st_sup.tender_id = 401  AND comparitive_st_tech_compliance.tender_id =  tender_id1
```

Comment: It is showing an error now "#1051 - Unknown table 'comparitive_st_sup' "

Comment: you need to select from both tables ` From  comparitive_st_sup, comparitive_st_tech_compliance`

Comment: its showing duplicated records..actually it should show only 3 records, its showing 9 records now

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT comparitive_st_sup.*,
  comparitive_st_sup.tender_id As tender_id1,
  comparitive_st_sup.supplier_name As supplier_name1,
  comparitive_st_sup.slno As slno1,
  comparitive_st_sup.prod_description As prod_description1,
  comparitive_st_sup.item_name As item_name1,
  comparitive_st_sup.total As total1,
  comparitive_st_tech_compliance.tech_analyst_comment
  FROM comparitive_st_sup, comparitive_st_tech_compliance
  WHERE comparitive_st_sup.tender_id = 401
  AND comparitive_st_tech_compliance.tender_id = comparitive_st_sup.tender_id
  GROUP BY comparitive_st_sup.tender_id;
```

Comment: Group By tender_id will not work since there will be more than one record with the same tender_id. When i ran your query, its just showing one record instead of 3 records...